# Difference between global scss file and scss file for component in Angular

Tags: angular, stylesheet, angular7

In a recent Angular 7 project, I have a component (defined in the file `file-list.component.ts`) in which there is a `mat-paginator` (a component from Angular material component library). When I want to change the background color of the `mat-paginator`, I first tried to put

```
.mat-paginator-container {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

in `film-list.component.scss` (the stylesheet for associated with this component),  the background color of the paginator did not change. When I put this in `app.component.scss`, it did not work either. But when I put it in the `src/styles.css`, the background color is correctly changed. 

So my questions are:

- What is the difference between `src/styles.scss`, `app.component.scss` and `film-list.component.scss`?
- What is the scope of each of these files?
- What is the influence of `body` selector used in these stylesheet files?

Comment: Component stylesheets are scoped to the component. The global stylesheet isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**src/styles.scss**

Is for global CSS that will be applied across all the application and all the components. Here you can apply styling to `body` without problem.

**example.component.scss**

Is the CSS that will be scoped and applied to this specific component only. Here you won't be able to apply styling to `body` element.

**You can still pierce the scoped boundaries...**

When using components like `mat-paginator` inside, let say `example.component.ts` for example, the CSS from `mat-paginator` is in fact "outside" the `example.component.ts` component scope because `mat-paginator` has its own scope. Therefore you can pierce through the shadow-dom using **::ng-deep** to apply CSS.

Working example with the code below: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53241725

```css
/* not working because the class is not directly inside this component */
.mat-paginator-container {
  background: yellow;
}

/* working because `ng-deep` pierce through the shadow-dom */
::ng-deep .mat-paginator-container {
  background: red;
}
```

**Suggested Documentation**

Official Angular documentation about styling:
https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Great blog that explains CSS encapsulation: https://blog.angular.io/the-state-of-css-in-angular-4a52d4bd2700

Comment: ::ng-deep is being deprecated (without a clear alternative) iirc