# how to use angular material form field and flex-layout

Tags: angular-flex-layout, angular-material-7

I want to have 2 form input fields in one row: 
1. the first has a fixed with,
1. the second should grow and shrink, but this does not shrink below 180px.

Here is a full [stack-blitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-form-input)

When you start the app, we see this
[image]

There **maybe another issue**:
I think the 2nd input field should already show the hint text and the horizontal line - but it will only show it when it get's the focus.
Is this the expected behaviour or am I missing something?

Anyway. The main issue is that the **2nd field does not shrink** as expected. It will not shrink below 180px:
[image]

In the chrome dev-tool I can see that the `input` element is wrapped with a `div class="mat-form-field-infix">` and the class `mat-form-field-infix` has a fixed width of 180px!

The only **workaround** that I came up with is to override this width with using **`::ng-deep`**.
You can activate this in the [co-input-field.component.scss](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-form-input?file=app%2Fco-input-field%2Fco-input-field.component.scss) file of the Stackblitz example

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
  // width: auto !important;
  width: unset !important;
}
```

With this workaround the 2nd input shrinks as expected:
[image]

But [::ng-deep is deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) and will be removed.
So **what is the right way** to make the input shrink as expected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

since .mat-form-field-infix has a fixed width of 180px there is no way of making form field shrink beyond 180px. inevitably .mat-form-field-infix must be overridden.

you can achive the same result with ::ng-deep in a couple of ways;

1.disable view encapsulation for that particular component. However, this approach has a huge drawback that all the styles in your component becomes global so they need to be managed carefully.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-co-input-field',
    templateUrl: './co-input-field.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./co-input-field.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class CoInputFieldComponent {}
```

and then in `co-input-field.component.scss` you do the following

```
app-co-input-field {
    .mat-form-field-infix {
      width: auto !important;
    }
    // all other component styles goes in here
    // in order to keep them isolated from global scope
}
```

2.don't disable view encapsulation. use the element selector of parent component in global styles.

put the following in `styles.scss`

```
app-co-input-field {
    .mat-form-field-infix {
      width: auto !important;
    }
    // co-input-field.component.scss still can be used for encapsulated styles
}
```

3.don't disable view encapsulation. define a global rule for this particular situation.

put the following in `styles.scss`

```
.shrinking-mat-form-field {
    .mat-form-field-infix {
      width: auto !important;
    }
}
```

and apply the `.shrinking-mat-form-field` class to corresponding element

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%" class="shrinking-mat-form-field">
  <input matInput placeholder="placeholder"  />
  <mat-hint align="end">hint text</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

Even though second and third approaches are fundamentally same I personally prefer the third approach in order to make it readable, keep it consistent over the project, have minimal side effects and manage them from a single point.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53241725/1041641) to a related question about view-encapsulation to answer why the same css in the global `styles.scss` works differently than in the `component.scss`

Answer (score -1):

```
:host ::ng-deep.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-infix {
  padding: 0.4375em 0;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.